# How to delete localRefs and/or create a globalRefs for phonegap in Android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, c++, cordova

I have been banging my head with an issue with in my phonegap app for android that crashes on load because of the amount of images that the app requires.

In all other apis it runs fine.

With research I have found that I need to delete the localRefs and/or create a globalRef

I need help with this big time.

I found this and many others like it.

https://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/fe30e44a42e03efb?pli=1

I do not know where to begin to delete the localRefs or add globalRefs with in my project.  Can someone please give me detailed insturctions on where to begin and where to add the code to make these changes.

Thank you.